# draw contours with mouse on C# winform with Cyotek.ImageBox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, draw

The function I want is to let user use mouse to draw contours of several object on the image. Display the contours on the image, and be able to export the contours data. I'm using cyotek.imagebox here https://github.com/cyotek/Cyotek.Windows.Forms.ImageBox, a custom control for displaying image.
   Here's my approach.

```
private List<List<Point>> contours = new List<List<Point>>();    //a list to store all contours

private List<Point> contour_temp= new List<Point>();    //a list to store the contour the user is drawing

private bool mousedown // a flag that change when mouse up/mouse down event is triggered

private void imageBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     mousedown = true;
}

private void imageBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mousedown = false;
}

private void imageBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //drawing occurs when mouse is down, a contour is finish drawing when mouse is up
    // when a contour finish drawing. it will be added to the contours list and the contour temp will be clear

    if (draw_on) // a flag for this function to be active
    {
        if (contour_temp.Count > 0)
        {
            if (mousedown)
            {
                if (imageBox.IsPointInImage(e.Location)) //function cyotek.imagebox provides , it translate the mouse location to pixel location
                {
                    Point p = this.imageBox.PointToImage(e.Location);
                    if (p != contour_temp[contour_temp.Count - 1])
                        contour_temp.Add(p);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (contour_temp.Count > 2)
                {
                    contours.Add(contour_temp);
                    contour_temp.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (mousedown)
            {
                contour_temp = new List<Point>();
                Point p = this.imageBox.PointToImage(e.Location);
                contour_temp.Add(p);
            }
        }
        imageBox.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void imageBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //at the painting function, always paint all the contours stored
    //if mouse is down, print the temporary contour the user is currently drawing
    foreach (List<Point> contour in contours)
    {
        Point p0 = contour[0];
        foreach (Point p1 in contour)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), imageBox.GetOffsetPoint(p0), imageBox.GetOffsetPoint(p1));//Cyotek.ImageBox provided, get the correct point even after zooming
            p0 = p1;
        }    //draw all contours

    }

    if(draw_on && mousedown && contour_temp.Count>0)
    {

        Point p0 = contour_temp[0];
        foreach (Point p1 in contour_temp)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Green), imageBox.GetOffsetPoint(p0), imageBox.GetOffsetPoint(p1));
            p0 = p1;
        }// draw the contour user is drawing

    }
  }
```

The draw contour_temp part works fine. But the program crash when a contour finished drawing, throwing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException on 'mscorlib.dll',
After some tests, I discover that the draw all contours thing in paint function
is somehow wrong. I've done some research about the exception, saying the index
of list is out of bound. But how could it happened when I'm using "foreach"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to these lines here:

```
contours.Add(contour_temp);
contour_temp.Clear();
```

In the first case, you're adding the list of temporary points `contour_temp` to your main list `contours`, but as `List<T>` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) you're not adding a copy of the points, but a reference to the **same** list - which you then clear, causing `contours` to actually consist of just empty lists. But your painting routine expects those lists to always contain at least one point, hence the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when trying to paint as you're trying to get the first item in a list where no items exist.

I fixed your demo program by changing the first line to

```
contours.Add(new List<Point>(contour_temp));
```

This will create a copy of the list, thus preserving the points. I tested your demo program with this correction and it worked fine.

Hope this helps. And thanks for using ImageBox!

Comment: And thank you again for the convenient imagebox control.
By the way, I've asked another question on the Cyotek forum about imagebox. Could you take a look?